# Decimal.Parse throws a FormatException

Tags: c#, decimal, formatexception

I tried to use the decimal.parse  as described at : 
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cafs243z(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cafs243z%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

So i copied from this page the following example:

```
   string value;
   decimal number;
   value = "1.62345e-02";
   try
   {
       number = Decimal.Parse(value);
       Console.WriteLine("'{0}' converted to {1}.", value, number);
   }
   catch (FormatException)
   {
       Console.WriteLine("Unable to parse '{0}'.", value);
   }
```

And i got a FormatException, 
Do you have an idea why it's happened?

thanks, 
eyal

Comment: Wrong Locale for the thread, expecting a , instead of a .???

Comment: specify the CultureInfo in the Parse.

Comment: I'm pretty sure `Decimal.Parse` doesn't handle e notation by default - the documentation you copied this from even tells you this won't work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
using System.Globalization;
using System.Text;

....

number = Decimal.Parse(value, NumberStyles.AllowExponent|NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint);
```

In order to parse a number in exponential format, you need to set the appropriate flags from `NumberStyles Enumeration` as described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberstyles%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 10):

[shree.pat18's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23604784/447156) is of course right. But I want to explain this question a little bit more if you let me..

Let's look at how [`Decimal.ToParse(string)` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cafs243z%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) [implemented](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/decimal.cs#17d9bd19190be769);

```
public static Decimal Parse(String s)
{
   return Number.ParseDecimal(s, NumberStyles.Number, NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo);
}
```

As you can see, this method uses [`NumberStyles.Number`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Globalization.NumberStyles.aspx) by default. It is a composite number style and it's [implemented](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/globalization/numberstyles.cs#cf3733616e2bd9e9) like;

```
Number   = AllowLeadingWhite | AllowTrailingWhite | AllowLeadingSign | AllowTrailingSign |
           AllowDecimalPoint | AllowThousands,
```

That means your string can have one of;

- Leading and trailing white spaces (where [`Char.IsWhiteSpace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.char.iswhitespace%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) returns `true`)
- Current culture's leading or trailing sign ([`PositiveSign`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.positivesign%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [`NegativeSign`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.negativesign%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) )
- Your current culture's [`NumberDecimalSeparator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.numberdecimalseparator%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
- Your current culture's [`NumberGroupSeparator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.numbergroupseparator%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Since `NumberStyles.Number` has `AllowDecimalPoint`, it fits `.` in your string but this style doesn't have `AllowExponent` that's why it can't parse `e-02` in your string.

That's why you need to use [`Decimal.Parse Method (String, NumberStyles)` overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/91fwbcsb%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) since you can specify `NumberStyles` yourself.

Comment: Thanks @SergeyBerezovskiy I try to teach him how to fish instead of give him a fish.

Comment: In most cases (e.g. input coming from files) you will also want to use NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo, that is use the overload Parse(String, NumberStyles, IFormatProvider). Regardless of whether you want to use the system culture or an invariant culture case it's best to be specific and pass a NumberFormatInfo argument. The next developer can see immediately what format of decimal points etc. is expected.

Comment: @AndersForsgren _Unfortunately_, OP never told use what his `CurrentCulture` exactly. That's why I assume his culture uses `.` as a `NumberDecimalSeparator` of his current culture. You have a point about using `IFormatProvider` would be more clear in most cases. But `InvariantInfo` is _culture-independent_. It uses `InvariantCulture` settings. That's why always using `InvariantInfo` might not be a good idea. Of course these all depends on inputs.

Comment: +1 for the detailed answer and an implicit +1 for the philosophy behind it.

Comment: @SonerGönül I agree we need more details here, but regardless, it is good to be explicit: I recommend passing CurrentCulture even if it is equivalent to omitting the argument. As for Current vs. Invariant, I find 99% of bugs (almost weekly, since I work in a culture with decimal comma) are due to code that didn't think about it and used default (system culture) even though what they meant was to use an InvariantCulture. The opposite kind of bug I have almost never seen!

Comment: @AndersForsgren If you say so :)